# How do I get the "LocalPath" for a linked ProjectItem?

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

Using T4, I'm trying to get the full path of a linked `ProjectItem`. I'm only able to get the "source" full path. I'd like to get the full path of the "target" project (that is, the project which links the original file).

How do I do so? I've spent the best of 2 hour reading docs and searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can concat parent full path and item name like this:

```
itemFullPath = ((ProjectItem)item.Collection.Parent).Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.ToString() + item.Name;
```